# Batch Self-Altering Script

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch script that in essence is an infinite loop which resets after pause>nul. However, I need a way to replace every set /p to a set in order to remove the prompting while still showing the input that was given in the previous loop. Can I implement something into this script to self-edit all of the set /p's to set's?

```
@echo off
title 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
:a
cls
set /p a=Hello, world
echo %a%
pause>nul
goto a
```

The output that I desire after the first loop is:

```
@echo off
title 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
:a
cls
set a=Hello, world
echo %a%
echo %a%
pause>nul
goto a
```

Can somebody please explain to me Aacini's answser because it seems to work perfectly.

Comment: Please Show us the script you want to Self-Alter, and the code you have to do so so far.

Comment: I have updated the post to show the script.

Comment: I have updated it again with the desired output.

Comment: A running batch file that edits itself has to deal with the CMD pointers that keep track of where it is up to in the script.  This is a byte position and not a line position, so if the script adds more bytes or less bytes when it performs the change, then an error or unintended behaviour will occur.

Comment: Sooo what would you recommend that I do?

Comment: It depends on exactly what the task is - there may be another way to do what you are after.  When you reply, add @foxidrive - the writer of a question or answer always gets the reply notification but otherwise I won't see your comment.

Answer (score 2):

This solve your original request of replace *every* `set /p ...` commands by `set ...` ones:

```
@echo off
title 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set pSwitch=/p
:a
cls
set %pSwitch% a=Hello, world
echo %a%
pause>nul
set "pSwitch="
goto a
```

Just use the `set %pSwitch% ...` format in all commands you want to change.

**EDIT**: *Reply to the comments*

In your example you changed a `set /p var=Prompt` command by `set var=Prompt`, that is, after the first loop you assign *the Prompt* to the variable! Just after read your last comment I realized that you want "to store variables that are inputted by the user permanenetly". You may do that this way:

- At beginning of your program, insert: `call :initVars`.
- Change each `set /p var=Prompt` command by `call :mySet var="Prompt"`.
- At end of your program, insert:

.

```
:mySet var="Prompt"
if not defined %1 (
   set /P "%1=%~2"
   echo set "%1=!%1!" >> "%~F0"
)
exit /B

:initVars
```

For example:

```
@echo off
title 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
call :initVars

:a
cls
call :mySet a="Hello, world"
echo %a%
pause>nul
goto a

:mySet var="Prompt"
if not defined %1 (
   set /P "%1=%~2"
   echo set "%1=!%1!" >> "%~F0"
)
exit /B

:initVars
```

Comment: This is exactly what was posted above, but I need to do this for multiple variables which are defined in different stages of the infinite loop.

Comment: This solution "replace all of the set /p's to set's" as you requested, after executed _anyone_ of the set /p's. Do you want to selectively replace _one_ set /p to set after execute it? In your request you mention "every set /p to a set" two times...

Comment: I mean this in the sense that there will be multiple set /p's that are entered in various loops and so I'm trying to execute each set /p before changing it to a set.

Comment: Answer in two parts: 1. There is no way in Batch that _the same code_ behaves differently when placed on different lines in the program. This means that you must define a different variable for each `set /p` command. 2. What is the purpose of this change? Perhaps we may solve this problem in a different way. For example, execute `set /p` if the variable is _not defined_ and `set` otherwise...

Comment: What I am trying to do is to make an efficient way to store variables that are inputted by the user permanenetly. That's basically what I'm trying to do in essence along with doing this multiple times in different loops.

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Store the variables in a file and read them in a for /F loop.

Comment: Could you explain this answer step by step because I've found that it works perfectly and I'd like to know how it does.

Comment: If you could please assist me I'd be very grateful

Answer (score 1):

idk what you have tried, or what your script looks like, but try something like this.

```
set p=/p var=prompt
:a
set %p%
pause>nul
set p=var=prompt
goto a
```

if this doesnt help, please describe your issue further.

ps, not at a windows comp right now, so cant test this.

Comment: The only problem I see with this is that it would leave the variable permanently as var=prompt after the first loop. I need an alteration that allows for p to be used as '/p var=prompt' when it is executed the first time, but then altered to 'var=prompt' for the next execution.

Comment: monacraft, it does work. it does exactly what it was supposed to do, as at the time, i had no code to go off of except a goto loop, a cls, and a pause.

Comment: OP, i beleive that is what this does, the first execution of the loop, it prompts, after that, it just sets. however, if the case is that i misunderstood your issue, i would be happy to delete my answer.

Comment: I need to do this for multiple variables which are defined in different stages of the infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

This will ask for a value the very first time and use "Hello, world" in all other runs in the loop (that is what your example suggests):

```
@echo off
set "a="
    :a
if not defined a ( set /p "a=Hello, world:" ) else ( set a=Hello, world )
echo %a%
pause>nul
goto :a
```

This is, what *I think* you want: asking for a value the first time and use *this value* in all other runs:

```
@echo off
set "a="
    :a
if not defined a (set /p "a=Hello, world:") else (echo %a%)
pause>nul
goto :a
```

Comment: Placing if statements for each variable would be tedious but this is something along the lines of what I'm looking for. Can this be done in a way that suits more variables in an effective manner?